# How do i update a value of a primary key on windows azure

Tags: mysql, database, azure

Well I have to edit my primary key value 
I tried to do this but when I edit the primary key that send me an error msg this is the code...

```
    internal void ModificarVendedor(string codigo,string telefono, DateTime fecha,string nombre,string codAntiguo)
    {
        var repa = cnx.REPARTIDORs.Where(e => e.codigo == codAntiguo).FirstOrDefault();
        repa.nombre = nombre;
        repa.codigo = codigo;
        repa.telefono = telefono;
        repa.fechaContrato = fecha;
        Commit();
    }
```

"codigo" is the primary key who I have to update...

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: It say i cant update the primary key. I think it is because "codigo" is a foreign key for another tables :s

Comment: The whole point of a primary key is that it doesn't change. If it's also an FK to another table as you say, then a) that will explain why your update doesn't work and b) your design is absolutely rotten! Post another question showing your current design and explaining what the tables are and your desired relationships between them.